# Ubuntu Server VirtualBox host-only adapter confusion (windows 7 host)

Tags: virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

really hoping this is right place to ask this question seeing that my host is a Windows 7 machine. I have 3 Ubuntu Server 12.04 VMs set up through VirtualBox 4.1.18, and envisage the following usage:

- **LAMP** - for Drupal, Moodle and other arbitrary PHP test applications (additionally a few of the Drupal installs need to communicate with some internet services)
- **SSH** - to SFTP to the `/var/www` directory using FileZilla from Win7
- **SMTP service** - for Drupal and Moodle installs to send test emails out from them.

Before I continue, I must stress that I'm not deeply knowledgeable with regard to networking in general, but I did read up on a few things to not make a complete fool of myself here!

I only have a single machine on my physical network - a laptop which connects to my router via WiFi and which picks up:

- DHCP enabled = Yes
- IPv4 = 192.168.1.6
- Subnet Mask = 255.255.255.0
- IPv4 Default Gateway = 192.168.1.254

And currently under NAT, VirtualBox assigns an IP of `10.0.2.15` to my VM.

I started reading the following article ([Host-Only Networking With VirtualBox](http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox)) which was exactly what I wanted to accomplish, and got a good idea of how to setup NAT and Host-Only adapters for each desired VM. However I then got confused when I read this article ([Networking between host and guest VMs in VirtualBox](http://www.slideshare.net/powerhan96/networking-between-host-and-guest-v-ms-in-virtual-box)).

VirtualBox > File > Preferences > Network > Edit Host-only adapter, shows me an IPv4 address of `192.168.56.1` and Mask of `255.255.255.0`. Would the following configuration for `/etc/network/interfaces` be correct for static IP under the VM:

```
# The host-only network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.56.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

I am confused about the second referenced article mentioning that NAT will give `10.0.2.15` on **eth0**, but then Host-only **eth1** should be static and set to `10.1.2.1*`. From the article: "*Each NAT adapters and Host-only adapter should not reside in same sub-network*". What should my **eth1** interface block above contain? I am hesitant to try various options in case I end up breaking something, which why I'm asking here first...basically, *What is the right way to this*?

Thank you having the patience to read my question. Sincerely hope you can help me. TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The host-only adapter allows the host and the VM to communicate with each other over the network. In other words, that is what is used when you SFTP to the `/var/www` directory. The host-only adapter in the VM must be on the same subnet as the virtual adapter on the host. On my system, it looks like this:

Host: 192.168.56.1

VM:   192.168.56.3

The NAT adapter in my VM has been assigned to 10.0.2.15, which doesn't match any of the adapters in the host.

Comment: Thank you! I bit the bullet and set up a new Ubuntu VM with NAT as Adapter 1, and then after installation was completed I shut the Vm down, enabled Network Adapter 2 as Host-only and restarted the VM. Edited the `interfaces` file as per my original post, rebooted the VM and an `ifconfig` showed that the change was registered. I can ping from the VM and download packages, and I can SFTP and SSH to it, and browse to LAMP apps from host browser. Thank you for confirming these for me.

Comment: in the *interfaces* file, what is `broadcast`? Is this similar to nameserver?

Comment: The braodcast ip is usually your network with 255 for the last octet: ip 192.168.0.1, netmask 255.255.255.0, network 192.168.0.0, broadcast 192.168.0.255. The broadcast address is used to send a message to all the computers connected to a LAN (by sending ONE message to the broadcast address.)